# Getting background to hide but not the content in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

My webpage's top looks like this, there is a homepage and a menu toggle that opens up a navigation bar.

[image]
[image]

Here's the code

```
<div class="logo">
<img style="margin-left:5%;height:100px;width:130px;vertical-align:middle" src="/download.png"  alt="" /> 
METRO RAIL SYSTEM</div>
```

```
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 1s;

  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  right: 5%;
  top: 4rem;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  /* background: red; */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Now, the `fixed` in `.logo` enables me to have title bar(image+text+backcolour) be fixed while I scroll down.

But, when I open the navigation bar, I only want to have my (image+text) there, but as you can see the background colour is also there.

Is there a workaround to do this? I assume I will have to get a background strip rather than colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the menu is toggled, add a CSS class (for eg `menu-open`) to the logo element and remove the background color using `transparent` keyword:

```
.logo.menu-open {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: simple yet perfect. there was already a class `.logo.active` to change the text colour when menu toggled, I added below it and works.

Comment: is it possible to make the title bar unfixed but when the scroll is near the top of page, and menu bar is toggled then title bar is not hidden beside (because it is unfixed)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maybe you're looking for `position: sticky`?  I'd recommend asking a new question (You can copy paste this and change it a little) with an [mcve] of what you've so far.